# RangeSlide: how to enable it?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

i'm just looking how to enable range slider on kendo slider for angular 2:
Here component page: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/slider/

So thanks.
Diego

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Kendo UI Slider for Angular 2 cannot be used as a range slider.